# How to get float values from string list

Tags: python

I have a column encodings in my sqllite database with datatype TEXT. For example, it is a str-type record: `[-0.008732336573302746, 0.02287052385509014].`
How to get float values from string list?

Comment: `float()` converts a string to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
my_list = eval("[-0.008732336573302746, 0.02287052385509014]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python’s built-in 
**eval()** to convert the string to python expression:

```
list_of_floats = eval(“[-0.34354989003, 1.4838348]”)
```